# Nikah between a syed ( female ) and a nonsyed ( male ) is possible in our religion or not?

Tags: nikah, fiqh

Mostly syed families don't accept marriage proposal from nonsyed families . What is in our religion Islam about marriage between a syed ( female ) and a nonsyed ( male )?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help] and our [Meta]. As to your post:What is syed and nonsyed? in Islam there's no difference between all the people.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Some people in Asia (esp India/Pakistan) "claim" they are directly related to the lineage of the Prophet. Hence, they do not accept Zakat or marry outside their own. I concur that in Islam there is no such restriction and many of these seem to be Bidah or egoistic behavior at the least.

Comment: @Ahmed the family of my sisters husband (father side) claims the same ;) as far as I know -if it is correct- they shouldn't accept zakat, anything else is rather bid'ah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some words from Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) last Sermon:

O People, listen to me in earnest, worship God (The One Creator of the Universe), perform your five daily prayers (Salah), fast during the month of Ramadan, and give your financial obligation (zakah) of your wealth. Perform Hajj if you can afford to.

All mankind is from Adam and Eve, an Arab has no superiority over a non-Arab nor a non-Arab has any superiority over an Arab; also a white has no superiority over a black nor a black has any superiority over white except by piety and good action. Learn that every Muslim is a brother to every Muslim and that the Muslims constitute one brotherhood. Nothing shall be legitimate to a Muslim which belongs to a fellow Muslim unless it was given freely and willingly. Do not, therefore, do injustice to yourselves. [Reference](https://www.introductiontoislam.org/prophetlastsermon.shtml)

I think this reference is enough for the answer you are looking for.